# WPF: Binding ContextMenu to visual parent

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, dependency-properties, visual-tree

I know `ContextMenu`s aren't part of the visual tree, but I've been trying to bind the `Visibility` property of a `ContextMenu` to a property on its parent `UserControl`. So far I've tried ancestor binding and experimented with a converted, but the only way that seems remotely feasible at the minute is to use a `MultiValueConverter` and reflection to pass the type names and property names on the `UserControl`. Even then I'm not sure it would work.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a context menu is only visible when you right click, so you should not need to set its visibility. maybe you should be using a popup.

however if you want to do some funky bindings you can use [element spy](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/) from the excellent josh smith to use element name bindings to bind between things that arent usually possible.

Comment: That's a really great helper class. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou. I found this question/answer while looking for a solution to something else. `ElementSpy` is EXACTLY what I needed. +1 for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to bind the visibility of a ContextMenu... but anyway, here's a solution that should work :

```
<ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.Visibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```