# How to set a binding in WPF Toolkit Datagrid's ContextMenu CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to create a ContextMenu where I want to pass a currently selected index of the datagrid to a ViewModel using CommandParameter. The following Xaml code doesn't work. What might be the problem?

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MarketsRows}"
    <dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Add Divider"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}}"
                  Command="{Binding Path= AddDividerCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you checked the Debug console while debugging the app? If it's a binding problem you may likely find some data for troubleshooting it there...

Comment: I do get a binding error, I just don't know how to solve it:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedIndex; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A context menu is not part of the same visual tree. Ancestor bindings dont work as the context menu is not a child of the element it is on; in your case the datagrid.

There are some workarounds, Ive answered this question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617122/wpf-menuitem-command-binding-to-elementname-results-to-system-windows-data-error/2619041#2619041) and [here (kind of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051205/wpf-binding-contextmenu-to-visual-parent/2052966#2052966)

But what you are looking for is the placement target to do something like this (as long as AddDividerCommand is a property on the datagrid(i.e. the placement target)

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
 <MenuItem
    Header="Add Divider"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}"
    Command="{Binding Path=AddDividerCommand}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks! I only had to slightly modify DataContext:
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this in your CommandParameter,

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="MyHeader" 
                     Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I already tested it and it should work.